# Что с запросом?

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ua = UserAgent()
usr_agent = ua.chrome
headers ={
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

}
s = requests.Session()

res = s.get('https://cashtoyou.ru/',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

rr = soup.select('#reset-form-confirm > input[type=hidden]')
for i in rr:
    tok = i['value']

print(tok)

head = {

    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,pl-PL;q=0.8,pl;q=0.7,en-RU;q=0.6,en;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4',
    'content-length': '227',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
    'origin': 'https://cashtoyou.ru',
    'referer': 'https://cashtoyou.ru/',
    'content-encoding': 'gzip',
    'content-security-policy': 'upgrade-insecure-requests;',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'x-csrf-token':tok,
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

USR = '7900908215'
PASS = 'Dereshov84'
data = {
    '_csrf': tok,
    'LoginForm[username]': USR,
    'LoginForm[password]': PASS,
    'LoginForm[rememberMe]': '0',
    'LoginForm[rememberMe]': '1',
    'ajax': 'login-form'
}
res1 = s.post('https://cashtoyou.ru/login/validate',headers=head,data=data)

print(res1)
```

Comment: res = s.get('https://cashtoyou.ru/',headers=headers) print(res) <Response [403]> теже грабли в другой упаковке :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1451476/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc?noredirect=1#comment2592555_1451476

Comment: не может быть, попробуйте сменить user_agent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0'
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

res = s.get('https://cashtoyou.ru/')
print(res)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
tok = soup.select_one('#reset-form-confirm > input[type=hidden]')['value']

data = {
    '_csrf': tok,
    'LoginForm[username]': 'ssss@mail.ru',
    'LoginForm[password]': '123456',
    'LoginForm[rememberMe]': [
        '0',
        '1',
    ],
    'ajax': 'login-form',
}
headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}
response = s.post('https://cashtoyou.ru/login/validate/', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response)
print(response.json())


<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
{'loginform-password': ['Неверный логин или пароль']}
```

Comment: спасибо,а в чем была проблема?